# Python List-comprehension and referencing an object multiple times

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is a contrived example to demonstrate referencing the same dictionary item multiple times in a for-loop and a list-comprehension. First, the for-loop:

```
dict_index_mylists = {0:['a', 'b', 'c'], 1:['b', 'c', 'a'], 2:['c', 'a', 'b']}

# for-loop
myseq = []
for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    interim = dict_index_mylists[i]
    if interim[0] == 'b' or interim[1] == 'c' or interim[2] == 'a':    
        myseq.append(interim)
```

In the for-loop, the interim list is referenced from the dictionary object and is then referenced multiple times in the if-conditional which may make sense particularly if the dictionary is very large and/or on storage.  Then again, the 'interim' reference maybe unnecessary because the Python dictionary is optimized for performance.

This is a list-comprehension of the for-loop:

```
# list-comprehension
myseq = [dict_index_mylists[i] for i in [0, 1, 2] if dict_index_mylists[i][0] == 'b' or dict_index_mylists[i][1] == 'c' or dict_index_mylists[i][2] == 'a']
```

The questions are:

a. Does the list-comprehension make multiple references to the dictionary item or does it reference and keep a local 'interim' list to work on?

b. What is the optimal list-comprehension expression that contains multiple conditionals on the same dictionary item and where the dictionary is very large?

Comment: Saving that dict access is classic micro-optimization. It might make your code a few microseconds faster, but the dict has to be ridiculously large to make it worth your time.

Comment: @JochenRitzel: the size of the dictionary doesn't even matter, accessing a key is O(1) on average anyway.

Comment: @JochenRitzel Yep, it is probably micro-optimization but had to ask!

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: The point of the question is to eliminate those 3 extra `dict_index_mylists[i]` lookups. Each takes a extremely short  time to compute the hash and jump to it's location (that's the constant factor of a dict access). The question asks that if the dict large, might those extra lookups amount to something? This is generally not a question worth thinking about, as the time spent on hashing will not be significant unless you're dealing with at least a few million entries.

Comment: @JochenRitzel: it doesn't matter how many entries there are.  The code only does three lookups.  That's a constant-time operation regardless of the size of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking only about optimization of common sub-expressions.  In your list comprehension, it will index into the dictionary multiple times.  Python is dynamic, it is difficult to know what side effects an operation like `dict_index_mylists[i]` might have, so CPython simply executes the operation as many times as you tell it to.

Other implementations like PyPy use a JIT and may optimize away subexpressions, but it is difficult to know for sure what it will do ahead of time.

If you are very concerned with performance, you need to time various options to see which is best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at looking at python bytecode, but here's my attempt to learn something new this morning:

```
def dostuff():
    myseq = [dict_index_mylists[i] for i in [0, 1, 2] if dict_index_mylists[i][0] == 'b' or dict_index_mylists[i][1] == 'c' or dict_index_mylists[i][2] == 'a']

import dis
dis.dis(dostuff)
```

If you look at the output (below), there are 4 calls to `LOAD_GLOBAL`, so it doesn't look like python is storing an interim list.  As for your second question, what you have is probably about as good as you can do.  It's not as bad as you might think though.  `dict` objects access items by a hash function, so their lookup complexity is `O(1)` regardless of dictionary size.  Of course, you could always use `timeit` and compare the two implementations (with loop and list-comp) and then choose the faster one.  Profiling (as always) is your friend.

**APENDIX (output of dis.dis(dostuff))**

```
5           0 BUILD_LIST               0
            3 DUP_TOP             
            4 STORE_FAST               0 (_[1])
            7 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           13 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
           16 BUILD_LIST               3
           19 GET_ITER            
      >>   20 FOR_ITER                84 (to 107)
           23 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
           26 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict_index_mylists)
           29 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
           32 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           33 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           36 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           37 LOAD_CONST               4 ('b')
           40 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           43 JUMP_IF_TRUE            42 (to 88)
           46 POP_TOP             
           47 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict_index_mylists)
           50 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
           53 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           54 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           57 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           58 LOAD_CONST               5 ('c')
           61 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           64 JUMP_IF_TRUE            21 (to 88)
           67 POP_TOP             
           68 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict_index_mylists)
           71 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
           74 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           75 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
           78 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           79 LOAD_CONST               6 ('a')
           82 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           85 JUMP_IF_FALSE           15 (to 103)
      >>   88 POP_TOP             
           89 LOAD_FAST                0 (_[1])
           92 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict_index_mylists)
           95 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
           98 BINARY_SUBSCR       
           99 LIST_APPEND         
          100 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
      >>  103 POP_TOP             
          104 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
      >>  107 DELETE_FAST              0 (_[1])
          110 STORE_FAST               2 (myseq)
          113 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
          116 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: note that this list will lie to you on PyPy. There are indeed 4 LOAD_GLOBAL but the underlaying assembler might contain less assembler than that (or none at all)

Answer (score 0):

First point: nothing (expect 'myseq') is "created" here, neither in the forloop nor in the listcomp versions of your code - it's just a reference to the existing dict item.

Now to answer you questions : the list comp version will make a lookup (a call to `dict.__getitem__` for each of the `dict_index_mylists[i]` expressions. Each of these lookup will a return a reference to the same list. You can avoid these extra lookups by retaining a local reference to the dict's items, ie :

```
myseq = [
    item for item in (dict_index_mylists[i] for i in (0, 1, 2)) 
    if item[0] == 'b' or item[1] == 'c' or item[2] == 'a'
    ]
```

but there's no point in writing a listcomp just for the sake of writing a listcomp.

Note that if you don't care about the original ordering and want to apply this to your whole dict, using `dict.itervalues()` would be simpler.

wrt/ the second question, "optimal" is not an absolute. What do you want to optimize for ? space ? time ? readability ?

Comment: I've modified the question to remove the 'created' occurences.  In our case, the dictionary is traversed non-sequentially.  Optimization wrt time.  Thanks!

Comment: @dbv: then - and assuming you do want to stick to a listcomp - the above solution is probably as fast as possible. Oh and BTW, note that despite dicts being highly optimised, each lookup still requires a method call which has a cost by itself.